# Matplotlib x-axis formatter showing decimal seconds--won't go away

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, date-formatting, axis-labels

I'm still relatively new to Python and I'm having a bit of trouble with the axis formatter for `matplotlib`.

My axis uses `datetime` values and shows hours, minutes, seconds, and then decimal seconds. I want to get rid of the decimals and be able to show Year/day/month Hour:minute:second on the x-axis or something similar. To start with, I just tried to get Year/month/day. However, `DateFormatter` is seeming to have no effect.

I got much of my information from these two links: [format dates](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html) and [Matplotlib instruction](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DayLocator)

My shortened code is below:
`tft` is a list of lists (hence `tft[event_num]`) of the `datetime` type and spans over the course of several weeks with data to the nearest second.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from images_to_list import images_to_list
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

extra = Tk()
extra.update()


class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.event_num = 1
        # Create a container
        self.frame = Frame(master)

        self.fig = Figure()
        self.fig.set_size_inches(9,7)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
        self.fig.autofmt_xdate()
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')
        self.line2, = self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf2[self.event_num],'.')
        self.ax.set_ylim([0,3.5])
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master=self.frame)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=4)
        self.frame.grid(row=0,column=0)




app = App(extra)
extra.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the [major formatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter) for the `xticks`:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Note that `fmt_xdata` appears to change the format of the mouseover values on the x axis, not the ticks themselves.

Comment: fmt_xdata simply tilts the values shown on the x-axis so they don't overlap. Your solution with the major formatter fixed the solution. Thank you.